# How do i get roundoff javascript following

Tags: javascript

`<script>
Math.round(2.1);
</script>`

i need round off like this

**Actual Result**.
2.1 round is 2

2.6 round is 3

**Expect Result** 
2.1 round is 3

2.6 round is 3

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to round up, which is done using [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil):

```
Math.ceil(2.1)
```

gives

```
3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Use `ceil`:

```
Math.ceil(2.1);   // 3
Math.ceil(.95);   // 1
Math.ceil(4);     // 4
Math.ceil(7.004); // 8
```

> The Math.ceil() function returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a given number.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Math.ceil()`

Ceil rounds up!

```
var value = Math.ceil(old_value);
```